# Seam to CDI Migration

Tags: annotations, seam, cdi

We are migrating our application from JBoss Seam to CDI so as expected we had to change all the Seam annotations with their equivalent CDI annotations, So far for basic annotations we succeeded for example replaced `@In` with `@Inject` `@Name` with `@Named`  ,but we are having a hard time for finding the CDI equivalent for `@BypassInterceptors` ,`@Startup`, and `@Out`

How to do we achieve this in CDI.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for @Out, use @Produces (from javax.enterprise.inject)
for @Startup, use the equivalent from EJB or listen for context events via events and using JBoss Solder.
for @BypassInterceptors, you'll need to use some configuration of alternatives from beans.xml.  But I'm not sure I understand your current use of @BypassInterceptors to answer 100%

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking at http://www.jboss.org/jdf/migrations/seam2/open18_migration/, which yes, I wrote, but talking about doing a migration just like you're doing and should highlight most of the pitfalls you're going to hit.

Comment: That link is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140121194030/http://www.jboss.org/jdf/migrations/seam2/open18_migration